# Namespaces in Ruby Rake Tasks

Tags: ruby, rake

Are the following equivalent?

```
namespace :resque do
  task setup: :environment do
  end
end

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: **yes**. When running `rake resque:setup` both of these tasks will be invoked.

Rake will merge these tasks. You can test this by doing the following:

```
p Rake.application.tasks
```

Which in this case would return something like

```
[<Rake::Task resque:setup => [environment]>]
```

Which is  simply an Array holding a single `Rake::Task` object. You can also check the scope or list of namespaces for a task by doing:

```
p Rake.application.tasks.first.scope
  #=> ["resque"]
```

If you want to learn a little more on how the internals of Rake work, check out [Rake::Task](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/task.rb) and [Rake::TaskManager](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/task_manager.rb)